# Origin of 「セキ」 when used in game of go 碁

Tags: kanji, etymology

I have seen some sites attributing「セキ」to 関 as in:

- https://jisho.org/search/%E9%96%A2
- https://yuki19925704.com/igo-seki/ (scroll to section that talks about 囲碁の「セキ」の語源)

However, the classic term in Chinese is 持 and I saw this word being mentioned in:

- https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8C%81%E7%A2%81
- https://www.ntkr.co.jp/igoyogo/yogo_497.html
- https://ouc.daishodai.ac.jp/files/ams_labo/publication/bulletin/%5BPDF%EF%BC%9A414KB%5D.pdf

I am curious about two things:

1. does セキ actually have ties with any of classic Chinese terms such as
   関 or 持?
2. or perhaps セキ is a Japanese invention that just happened to become more commonly used?

**Additional References**

- [Wiki about セキ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD_(%E5%9B%B2%E7%A2%81))
- [English Wiki about セキ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Go_terms#Seki)

Comment: I was able to find an entry about セキ in [kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD-86730#E3.83.96.E3.83.AA.E3.82.BF.E3.83.8B.E3.82.AB.E5.9B.BD.E9.9A.9B.E5.A4.A7.E7.99.BE.E7.A7.91.E4.BA.8B.E5.85.B8.20.E5.B0.8F.E9.A0.85.E7.9B.AE.E4.BA.8B.E5.85.B8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [関 entry in Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%A2-86733) is backed by a version of the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 that doesn't include as much detail as my local copy, which includes this bit about the etymology:

> (動詞【どうし】「せく(塞)」の名詞化【めいしか】で、「堰(せき)」と同語源【どうごげん】)
> (Nominalization of verb *seku* [塞く, "to narrow and close off"], cognate with 堰 [*seki*, "dam"])

The very first sense line seems applicable to the usage for Go:

> ① 物事【ものごと】をささえとめること。また、そのもの。へだて。
> (1) To close off and stop something.  Or, the closing or stoppage.  Barrier.

The oldest citation for this sense is the [伊勢物語【いせものがたり】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BC%8A%E5%8B%A2%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E), i.e. [*The Tales of Ise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Ise), dated to some time after 880.  This doesn't make any specific mention of the game of Go, but the definition seems very fitting for the sense used in the game: basically, "a blockage, an impasse".

Comment: Coincidentally, both 関 and 持 are both technical go term, recorded in Chinese classics 『玄玄碁経』and『棋経』by 張擬.


https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%84%E7%8E%84%E7%A2%81%E7%B5%8C

Comment: 関 refers to playing-move resembling "jump": https://senseis.xmp.net/?IkkenTobi.

while 持 means mutual-life in go (or commonly known/refer as セキ in Japanese terms). The word 持 has the meaning of perseverance in Chinese, so I feel it fits perfectly with セキ where the opposing groups are neither dead, but co-exists eternally.    


玄玄碁経: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8E%84%E7%8E%84%E7%A2%81%E7%B5%8C

Comment: I feel that certain sources (the ones I linked above) made the mistake of thinking that セキ comes from 関, since that the later is also one of the common surnames (pronounced similarly).

Anyway thank you for confirming that it is not something that had been clearly defined in authoritative sources.

Comment: The kanji 持 has no pronunciation in either Chinese or Japanese that resembles //seki// -- Chinese has variants of //ti//, //tʃi//, and //tsi//, while Japanese has //t͡ɕi// and //d͡ʑi// from the Middle Chinese, or //mot͡ɕi// as the native Japanese term (from verb 持【も】つ).  So just on phonetic grounds alone, we can say definitively that the Japanese Go term _seki_ is not from 持.

Comment: Be wary of trying to compare too much across languages.  Note that the "jump" sense is expressed in Japanese using the term _tobi_, not _seki_.  Chinese and Japanese are different languages, so uses of 関 in Chinese (traditional form 關, simplified form 关) may not align well with Japanese.  That said, I note [in the Wiktionary entry for Chinese 關](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%97%9C#Chinese) that the definitions include some similar senses as for Japanese _seki_: "to close, to shut; to lock up, to detain".

Comment: I agree that there are some commonalities of 関 across the two languages. I am hoping to find evidence to refute the connection of セキ and 関 strictly within the context of game of go.

The main reason I started the initial question, is that the go verbiage in English is heavily influenced by Japanese go terms. And I saw people commenting that the technical term "seki" refers to 関. Yet the classic Chinese sources do not support that claim. It's a pity that I am not fluent in Japanese, else I might be able to find clues in older Japanese text such as『爛柯堂棋話』

Comment: Funny enough, I found the answer in the [kotobank link](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%A2-86733) you shared!

⑨ (「持」「塞」の字をあてることもある)
囲碁で、攻合いの形になっている双方の一連の石が、互いに相手を取りに行くと自分のダメが詰まって逆に打ち上げられてしまう状態。せきの石で囲んだ点は地には数えないが、その中で取る石はハマとして地に換算される。せきはせきくずれまたはコウダテに使われない限り、生き石である。

:) What a relief. Thanks again!